# how can i change default camera direction in wpf helix toolkit

Tags: c#, wpf, toolkit, helix

```
<Grid>
    <hx:HelixViewport3D ZoomExtentsWhenLoaded="True" >
        <hx:SunLight/>
        <ModelVisual3D>
            <ModelVisual3D.Content>
                <GeometryModel3D>
                    <GeometryModel3D.Geometry>
                        <MeshGeometry3D x:Name="meshMain"
                    Positions="0 0 0  1 0 0  0 1 0  1 1 0  0 0 1  1 0 1  0 1 1  1 1 1"
                    TriangleIndices="2 3 1  2 1 0  7 1 3  7 5 1  6 5 7  6 4 5  6 2 0  2 0 4  2 7 3  2 6 7  0 1 5  0 5 4">
                        </MeshGeometry3D>
                    </GeometryModel3D.Geometry>
                    <GeometryModel3D.Material>
                        <DiffuseMaterial x:Name="matDiffuseMain">
                            <DiffuseMaterial.Brush>
                                <SolidColorBrush Color="Red"/>
                            </DiffuseMaterial.Brush>
                        </DiffuseMaterial>
                    </GeometryModel3D.Material>
                </GeometryModel3D>
            </ModelVisual3D.Content>
        </ModelVisual3D>
        <ModelVisual3D>
            <ModelVisual3D.Content>
                <GeometryModel3D>
                    <GeometryModel3D.Geometry>
                        <MeshGeometry3D x:Name="aaa"
                    Positions="1 1 1  2 1 1  1 2 1  2 2 1  1 1 2  2 1 2  1 2 2  2 2 2"
                    TriangleIndices="2 3 1  2 1 0  7 1 3  7 5 1  6 5 7  6 4 5  6 2 0  2 0 4  2 7 3  2 6 7  0 1 5  0 5 4">
                        </MeshGeometry3D>
                    </GeometryModel3D.Geometry>
                    <GeometryModel3D.Material>
                        <DiffuseMaterial x:Name="sa">
                            <DiffuseMaterial.Brush>
                                <SolidColorBrush Color="Red"/>
                            </DiffuseMaterial.Brush>
                        </DiffuseMaterial>
                    </GeometryModel3D.Material>
                </GeometryModel3D>
            </ModelVisual3D.Content>
        </ModelVisual3D>
        <hx:GridLinesVisual3D Width="8" Length="8" MinorDistance="1" MajorDistance="1" Thickness="0.01"/>
    </hx:HelixViewport3D>
</Grid>
```

How can I make that normally when you open the program you have the camera looking from the top ?

Pointed to you in helix toolkit.

So an user can see the 3d scene from the top and can move after if needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will show you step by step.

Add this `ShowCameraInfo="True"` into your `HelixViewport3D`

```
    <hx:HelixViewport3D ShowCameraInfo="True">
        ...
    </hx:HelixViewport3D>
```

Then run the program and click the right corner position box's up side there.
[image]

Then the view will be from top and you will see the camera informations on left corner. Save them somewhere.

[image]

Then finally we will put the values into your `HelixViewport3D`

```
<hx:HelixViewport3D ...>
    <hx:HelixViewport3D.Camera>
        <PerspectiveCamera Position="0 0 24.285"
                           LookDirection="0 0 -23.285"
                           UpDirection="0 1 0"/>
    </hx:HelixViewport3D.Camera>
    ...
</hx:HelixViewport3D>
```

And it's done!

For your example:

```
<Grid>
        <hx:HelixViewport3D ZoomExtentsWhenLoaded="True">
            <hx:HelixViewport3D.Camera>
                <PerspectiveCamera Position="0 0 24.285"
                                   LookDirection="0 0 -23.285"
                                   UpDirection="0 1 0"/>
            </hx:HelixViewport3D.Camera>
            <hx:SunLight/>
            <ModelVisual3D>
                <ModelVisual3D.Content>
                    <GeometryModel3D>
                        <GeometryModel3D.Geometry>
                            <MeshGeometry3D x:Name="meshMain"
                    Positions="0 0 0  1 0 0  0 1 0  1 1 0  0 0 1  1 0 1  0 1 1  1 1 1"
                    TriangleIndices="2 3 1  2 1 0  7 1 3  7 5 1  6 5 7  6 4 5  6 2 0  2 0 4  2 7 3  2 6 7  0 1 5  0 5 4">
                            </MeshGeometry3D>
                        </GeometryModel3D.Geometry>
                        <GeometryModel3D.Material>
                            <DiffuseMaterial x:Name="matDiffuseMain">
                                <DiffuseMaterial.Brush>
                                    <SolidColorBrush Color="Red"/>
                                </DiffuseMaterial.Brush>
                            </DiffuseMaterial>
                        </GeometryModel3D.Material>
                    </GeometryModel3D>
                </ModelVisual3D.Content>
            </ModelVisual3D>
            <ModelVisual3D>
                <ModelVisual3D.Content>
                    <GeometryModel3D>
                        <GeometryModel3D.Geometry>
                            <MeshGeometry3D x:Name="aaa"
                    Positions="1 1 1  2 1 1  1 2 1  2 2 1  1 1 2  2 1 2  1 2 2  2 2 2"
                    TriangleIndices="2 3 1  2 1 0  7 1 3  7 5 1  6 5 7  6 4 5  6 2 0  2 0 4  2 7 3  2 6 7  0 1 5  0 5 4">
                            </MeshGeometry3D>
                        </GeometryModel3D.Geometry>
                        <GeometryModel3D.Material>
                            <DiffuseMaterial x:Name="sa">
                                <DiffuseMaterial.Brush>
                                    <SolidColorBrush Color="Red"/>
                                </DiffuseMaterial.Brush>
                            </DiffuseMaterial>
                        </GeometryModel3D.Material>
                    </GeometryModel3D>
                </ModelVisual3D.Content>
            </ModelVisual3D>
            <hx:GridLinesVisual3D Width="8" Length="8" MinorDistance="1" MajorDistance="1" Thickness="0.01"/>
        </hx:HelixViewport3D>
    </Grid>
```

[image]